# Pandas - cumsum by month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Date          n
2014-02-27    4
2014-02-28    5
2014-03-01    1
2014-03-02    6
2014-03-03    7
```

I'm trying to get to one that looks like this

```
Date          n    csn
2014-02-27    4    4
2014-02-28    5    9
2014-03-01    1    1
2014-03-02    6    7
2014-03-03    7    14
```

...i.e. I want a column with the running total within the month and I want it to start over each month. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `.groupby()`, but don't just group by month, `groupby` year-month instead. Or else `2013-02` will be in the same group as `2014-02`, etc.

```
In [96]:

df['Month']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x[:7])
In [97]:

df['csn']=df.groupby(['Month'])['n'].cumsum()
In [98]:

print df
         Date  n    Month  csn
0  2014-02-27  4  2014-02    4
1  2014-02-28  5  2014-02    9
2  2014-03-01  1  2014-03    1
3  2014-03-02  6  2014-03    7
4  2014-03-03  7  2014-03   14

[5 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: you can directly ``df.groupby(df.index.month)`` if its a ``DatetimeIndex`` (which it should be)

Comment: Hope it is the case for OP. Agreed that it should be done so. But If `dtype` not specified, it gets read as `object` `dtype`.

Comment: agreed. (sometimes it helps to show the OP that you *should* do that as well), as was not clear how was read/constructed.

Comment: @Jeff df.index.month ignores year though, usually you'll want a TimeGrouper.

Comment: @AndyHayden ahh...yes that would be appropriate here

Answer (score 4):

If you're doing timeseries work, I recommend using a DatetimeIndex. In this example, you can use a TimeGrouper to group by month (which groups by year-month, like in a resample):

```
In [11]: g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))

In [12]: g['n'].cumsum()
Out[12]: 
Date
2014-02-27     4
2014-02-28     9
2014-03-01     1
2014-03-02     7
2014-03-03    14
dtype: int64

In [13]: df['csn'] = g['n'].cumsum()
```

Note: If you're not already using a DatetimeIndex, pass over the `to_datetime` function and set the index:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This now channged to `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq = 'M'))`